Showing integral of Berry curvature is invariant under small perturbations of states
Suppose I have a functional $S[f]= \int d^dx L(f(x), f'(x))$, and I want to argue that the functional is topological in some sense. Then what I imagine doing is calculating $S[f+\epsilon g] - S[f]$, and seeing that it is zero at first order in $\epsilon$.
I want to follow this exact same procedure with integrals of Berry curvature to verify that the resulting integral is topological in this sense (small perturbations of input states cannot change the value of the integration).
I have in mind the following integral. $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables, and $|u\rangle$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function of $x$ and $y$. One could view the space being integrated over as a torus.
$$I[|u \rangle] =i \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} dx dy (\partial_x \langle u|) (\partial_y |u\rangle) - (\partial_y \langle u|) (\partial_x |u\rangle)$$
How do I see that $I\left[\frac{|u \rangle + \epsilon |\delta\rangle}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon(\langle u|\delta\rangle + \langle \delta | u\rangle)+\epsilon^2 \langle \delta| \delta \rangle }}\right] - I\left[|u\rangle \right]$ vanishes at order $\epsilon$?
I am also OK with restricting $|\delta\rangle$ to be orthogonal to $|u\rangle$, in which case, dropping terms of $O(\epsilon^2)$ from the get-go, the goal would be to show that
$I\left[|u\rangle + \epsilon |\delta\rangle \right] - I\left[|u\rangle \right]$ vanishes at order $\epsilon$.

A few notes: $|u\rangle = |u\rangle(x,y)$ and $|\delta\rangle = |\delta\rangle(x,y)$ are functions of both the parameters $x,y$. One can choose $\epsilon$ real by absorbing its phase into $|\delta\rangle$. The norm $\langle \delta|\delta\rangle$ can also be a function of $x,y$.

Here is the start of a direct calculation for the simplified case where $|\delta\rangle$ and $|u\rangle$ are pairwise orthogonal.
$$I\left[|u\rangle + \epsilon |\delta\rangle \right] - I[|u \rangle] =i \epsilon \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} dx dy (\partial_x \langle u|) (\partial_y |\delta\rangle) - (\partial_y \langle u|) (\partial_x |\delta\rangle) + (\partial_x \langle \delta|) (\partial_y |u\rangle) - (\partial_y \langle \delta|) (\partial_x |u\rangle)$$
I had been hoping to massage the integrand above into some sort of total derivative, specifically one whose integral vanished, but I don't see a way forward. For this special case, since $\langle u | \delta \rangle = 0$, I was thinking I could use that $(\partial_i \langle u |) | \delta \rangle + \langle u | (\partial_i| \delta \rangle) = 0$.

This simple-minded approach is doomed to fail.  For one thing, $\vert u \rangle$ and $\vert \delta \rangle$ are likely ill-defined across the Brillouin zone.  It also worries me that no phase appears in your expansion: the whole business is about the phase shift during parallel transport.  Your best bet is to show that the curvature integrates to discrete values in general, and argue that no continuous deformation can change the discrete value.

@Vokaylop I agree with the "best bet" idea (I think similarly), but I'm still hoping that there may be a direct argument showing stationarity. Could you expand on $|u\rangle$ being ill-defined? I feel that I can generally choose a phase (depending on $\mathbf{k}$) such that $|u\rangle$ will be a smooth function with the same periodicity as the BZ; even if I can't, I'm happy restrict my question to $|u\rangle$ satisfying such constraints.

Mathematical fact: if the Chern number (i.e. Berry curvature integrated over the BZ) is non-zero, it is impossible to have a single patch of $\vert u \rangle$ that is both continuous and periodic over BZ.  Are you happy to restrict your proof to trivial bands?

@Vokaylop Thanks, I hadn't appreciated this. I feel like I can construct counterexamples, though I may be in error. Suppose the Hamiltonian were $$\sin(k_x) \sigma^x + \sin(k_y) \sigma^y + (1 - (\cos(k_x) + \cos(k_x))) \sigma^z$$ with BZ corresponding to $0\leq k_x <2 \pi$, $0\leq k_y<2 \pi$. For the lower-energy band, I find eigenfunctions proportional to $\left(\sqrt {\cos (k_x - k_y) + \cos (k_x + k_y) - 2\cos (k_x) -
2\cos (k_y) + 3} + \cos (k_x) + \cos (k_y) - 1, -\sin (k_x) -
i\sin (k_y)\right)^T.$

@Vokaylop After normalizing, I numerically get $I/(2 \pi) = -1$. However, plotting these states, they seem to be continuous and periodic, although they aren't smooth (they have cusps).  Here are some images of the plots https://i.sstatic.net/gYhyAh0I.png, https://i.sstatic.net/zOBpfDw5.png, https://i.sstatic.net/EszrKgZP.png.

Scratch that, the latter two images are showing point-like discontinuities at $(\pi, \pi)$. I might be OK with that, but I shouldn't be too hasty. Thanks for emphasizing the mathematical fact!

SE policy seems to be that I shouldn't continue on with a substantial discussion in the comment.  This is in response to OP's comments under the question itself.
Let's suppose that you can globally construct the eigenbasis $\lbrace\vert n; k \rangle\rbrace$ at every $k$ that varies smoothly with $k$, has well-defined phases, and respects the BZ periodicity.  Then the Berry connection $\vec{A}_n(k) = \langle n; k\vert i\partial_k \vert n;k\rangle$ is automatically periodic and well-defined throughout the BZ, and Berry curvature of the nth band is of course $F_n = \nabla \times \vec{A}_n$.
Stokes theorem immediately yields:
$$
\int_{BZ} F_n = \int_{\partial BZ} A_n = 0.
$$
Last equality follows from the periodicity of $A$: opposite edges of the BZ have the same (periodic) $A$, and the line integrals cancel out.  Periodicity implies zero Chern number.  The proof relies on  nothing except the mere existence of a periodic $\lbrace\vert n; k \rangle\rbrace$.
Of course the OP has explicitly cooked up a Hamiltonian that has a non-zero Chern number.  The only way to reconcile this is to break strict periodicity: the basis can only be periodic up to a gauge transformation.
